# Как передать умный указатель в функцию с обычным указателем?

Tags: c++, c, указатели, память, smart-pointer

Всем привет, мне нужно передать `shared_ptr` в функцию get которая принимает константный указатель на структуру, вот пример, скажите я правильно делаю? И если да, объясните пожалуйста вот это `&(*_info)`, что именно я разыменовываю? `shared_ptr` или `strct*`? И у чего именно я беру ссылку?
В моем понимании я разыменовал `shared_ptr` и взял ссылку на `strct`. И ещё, нужно ли будет мне чистить память внутри `shared_ptr` ведь он указывает на указатель

Код:

```
 std::shared_ptr<strct*> _info;
 _rv = get(&(*_info));
```

сигнатура функции get:

```
extern int get(const struct strct *_req);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У shared_ptr перегружен [оператор *](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator*) и Вы получаете внутренний объект. Потом Вы берете адрес этого. Это просто адрес внутреннего объекта. И сишная функция получает то, что она хочет. Освобождать как то память спецаильно нельзя. Но и сишная функция тоже не должна "освобождать память".

Но на самом деле можно ещё проще написать - для этого есть [функция get](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/get) - она как раз и предназначена для этого

```
_rv = get(_info.get());
```

На самом деле get значительно лучше Вашего "двойного способа". Если внутри `nullptr`, то разыменовывание приведет к UB, а `get` просто вернет `nullptr`.